# Como fazer um checkbox de SelectAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso criar um checkbox se ele estiver selecionado ele vai selecionar todos os outros e se ele não estiver selecionado os outros também devem estar desselecionados.

Tentei fazer algo porem não funcionou. Veja:

```
$("#selectAll").on('checked', function () {
   $(".checkReunioes").each(function( index ) {
      $( this ).attr("check", "checked");
   });
});
```

**Selecionar todos**:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox colorCheck">
   <label class="checkbox checkbox-dark">
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
   </label>
   <div id="nameSelectAll"></div>
</li>
```

**Restante dos inputs checkbox são gerados dinâmicamente**.

```
'<li class="item item-checkbox">'+
'  <label class="checkbox">'+
'       <input type="checkbox" class="checkReunioes">'+
'     </label>'+
'  <div data-uib="layout/card" data-ver="0">'+
((reunioes[i].COD_PESSO_LOCAL == "999") ? '<div class="">'+ reunioes[i].TXT_DESCR_ENDER +'</div>' : '<div class="">Casa '+ ((w_elemento == "M") ? "do " : "da ")+''+ reunioes[i].TXT_LOCAL_REUNI +' </div>')+
'   <div class="card_Data">'+DataInvertida+'</div>'+
'     <input id="codigoReuniao" value="'+reunioes[i].COD_IDENT_REUNI+'" hidden/>'+
'   </div>'+
'</li>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan, faça assim.

```
$("#selectAll").on('change', function () {

   var checked = this.checked;

   $(".checkReunioes").each(function(index, val) {

      $(this).prop("checked", checked);
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msyjs7ch/

********EDITADO

Para mudar o texto conforme a ação.

Primeiro para facilitar vamos mudar a estrutura do **HTML** adicionando uma tag **span**.

```
   <label class="checkbox checkbox-dark"> 
      <span class="textoSelecionarTodos">Selecionar todos</span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
   </label>
```

E agora nosso javascript fica assim

```
//isso é para otimizar e não fazer o jQuery buscar o mesmo elemento toda vez que o checkbox mudar
var $selectAllText = $('span.textoSelecionarTodos');

$("#selectAll").on('change', function () {

   var checked = this.checked;

   if(checked) {
       $selectAllText.text('Desmarcar todos');
   }
   else {
       $selectAllText.text('Selecionar todos');
   }

   $(".checkReunioes").each(function(index, val) {

      $(this).prop("checked", checked);
   });
});
```

Segue exemplo

http://jsfiddle.net/msyjs7ch/3/

Comment: O codigo não selecionou todos, na verdade selecionou nenhum

Comment: @RenanRodrigues veja aqui o código funcionando http://jsfiddle.net/msyjs7ch/

Comment: É funcionou sim kkkk, porque tinha bugado. Mais obrigado.

Comment: Amigo preciso adicionar uma questão, quando tiver marcar preciso que apareça o texto desmarcar todos, e quando não tiver marcar todos, como pego o evento de marcado para comparar ?

Comment: qual a estrutura HTML do seu checkbox de marcar e desmarcar, quero dizer onde vai ficar escrito marcar e desmarcar? Vou editar a resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: <div id="nameSelectAll"></div>

Comment: Você é 10, muito obrigado